# Deserialize badly designed XML

Tags: c#, xml-parsing

I'm in the process of refactoring some code that parses a pre-existing XML file (of which I did not create and cannot control the design).  Currently I read in the XML into an `XDocument` and perform all sorts of linq queries to extract the data.  What I want to do is to use XML **deserialization** to do all that work for me.

I want to do it this was as other sections of the code use XML deserialization (and I want to make the code consistent in operation) and also to better document the structure this XML file.

But buried 7 layers deep inside the XML is the following data:

```
<objects>
  <object name="Fred">
    <type>
      <BOOL/>
    </type>
  </object>
  <object name="Barney">
    <type>
      <WORD/>
    </type>
  </object>
  <object name="Wilma">
    <type>
      <derived name="Special1"/>
    </type>
  </object>
  <object name="Betty">
    <type>
      <array>
        <dimension upper="3" lower="0"/>
        <INT/>
      </array>
    </type>
  </object>
  <object name="Dino">
    <type>
      <array>
        <dimension upper="3" lower="0"/>
        <derived name="Special2"/>
      </array>
    </type>
  </object>
</objects>
```

Up until this point I had been able to get away with defining simple classes to model the XML.

But with the `object` data the value of the `Type` element is expressed as a sub-Element (and not an Attribute) for types that are well defined (EG `BOOL`, `WORD`).  In the case of a user defined type, a different sub-element is used, with the ultimate type name being defined in the `name` attribute of that sub-element (EG `Special1` or `Special2`).  (Also note that I don't/can't have a complete list of the standard types.)

(NOTE that while this XML is badly designed, it is **not malformed**. )

Then things get a little more confusing when the object is an array and the type is wrapped in an `array` element.

Ultimately I'd want the `type` (encompassing both standard and user defined) and `array dimensions` as properties of the `object` class (and an indicator that a `derived` type was encountered).

I am not sure how to build a class that could be deserialized from this XML, however I suspect that I need to delve into some custom XML processing for just this class (or perhaps an XSLT transformation?).

Comment: Manual serialization seems more optimal, then trying re-design something, to be able to use `XmlSerializer`. Because you may have to tune it a lot with attributes, or alter type itself (create it dynamically?). So why not handmade manual reading/saving?

Comment: @Sinatr I am not following what you mean, so can you expand on your comment?

Comment: Does the XML have an XML schema (XSD or DTD) at the top of the document? You'd need to come up with an XSD at the end of the day to automatically serialize/deserialize from a complex object.

Comment: @AlexandruPuiu There is no defined schema and given the inconsistencies between different sections of documents I doubt there ever was one and the 3rd party is relying on hand coded techniques (which given this example of XML and the company involved, it is no big surprise).  But with 2 other different documents from the same place I have successfully deserialized complex objects without a XSD/DTD, that have 7 layer deep hierarchies and 12 different objects - but they were well behaved XML (including the 6k of binary data in individual <hex>..</hex> digit elements - each on its own line!) .

Comment: If you only need parts of the document, I suggest you take a look at alternatives to the native XML libraries, and possibly use CsQuery or HtmlAgilityPack, I believe CsQuery has the ability to read badly formatted XML and repair it. Syntax is the same as jQuery selectors are for html. Also for the above XML you posted, your best bet would be to use inheritance for the objects you're mapping to.

Comment: @AlexandruPuiu I pretty well need all of the document.  Also while the XML is badly designed .. it is not malformed, so changing to another method of reading the file while still needing me to manually construct the class doesn't seem to save me anything.  Finally can you expand on how you would use inheritance to solve my issue?

Comment: The objects you deserialize to must match the above schema, so the names of the objects must match the element in question. I can see you running into trouble with reserved class names, but you might be able to work around that. You'd have one class named object with a property for name, and one for type. Type contains a List<ElementBase>, public abstract class ElementBase { public string Name { get; set; } }, then public class Array : ElementBase

Answer (score 1):

Why `to use XML deserialization to do all that work for me`?

You have done it already manually, why do you want to do extra work? And extra work would be: a lot of classes, with a lot of substitutions (to have that `<type>` to example) via [`attributes`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2baksw0z.aspx).

Or, continue my example, if you wish [here](http://dotnetfiddle.net/RExSEi).

---

[Here](http://dotnetfiddle.net/GpfIe4) is deserialization, as you can see, it's totally the same.

Just for convenience, I'll post code here:

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Serialization;

public class Program
{
    [Serializable]
    [XmlRoot("Objects")]
    public class MyXml
    {
        [XmlElement("Object")]
        public MyObject[] MyObjects;
    }


    [Serializable]
    [XmlRoot("Object")]
    public class MyObject
    {
        [XmlAttribute("name")]
        public string MyName;
        [XmlElement("Type")]
        public object MyType;
    }

    public static void Main()
    {
        var data = new MyXml();
        data.MyObjects = new MyObject[] {new MyObject() { MyName = "Fred"}, new MyObject()};
        using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            var space = new XmlSerializerNamespaces();
            space.Add("", "");
            var serializer = new XmlSerializer(data.GetType());
            serializer.Serialize(stream, data, space);
            var text = Encoding.Default.GetString(stream.ToArray());
            foreach(var line in text.Split(System.Environment.NewLine.ToCharArray(), StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries))
            Console.WriteLine(line);

            stream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
            var test = serializer.Deserialize(stream) as MyXml;
            Console.WriteLine("\nTest: " + test.MyObjects[0].MyName);

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I want to use XML deserialization partly to help self document the XML  file, and partly to bring the code base in line with other sections that use the same methodology on different XML files.  I already know how to do straight forward XML serialization and my example `object` is already 7 layers deep in a class hierarchy of around 22 classes.    But from what I see your example does not appear to solve my question as how to DE-serialize the `type`

Comment: This doesn't solve my problem of how to uniformly extract the value of the `Type` which is specified as `<BOOL/>` `<WORD/>` etc

Comment: If you don't mind namespaces here and there, then it's easy: just create base class (which will be used to hold items) and inherit from it one what is `<bool/>` and one what is `<word/>` (and so on). Holder class can be any parent (it can be `<object>` or `<type>`).

Answer (score 0):

As it was already said, I do not see any other alternative other than handling it manually, as you are already doing.

If neither you (probably nor the XML owner) do not know how the XML will be (schema-wise speaking), why do you think any technique could automatically understand?

So, I think you got it right in doing it manually.

Comment: Because I am a relative neophyte with XML serialization I was hoping to discover a technique that I had overlooked.  For example a hook that would allow manually handling just this one stupidity rather than having to handle the entire file manually.

Comment: Well, the thing is that when you have bad design (saying: your XML is not taken care gracefully via DTD or schemas), you will always find troubles that you can't overcome. I suggest you try to speak with the owner of the XML to build a schema for it, there are tools that build schemas based on the XML. And by having a schema, you will be able to deserialize it gracefully, however, you would still need to parse the stuff to Bool, or dword, as you are converting a string (whose type is defined in a string) to a real type. Then you need to manually do things.

Comment: Regarding tools to automatically generate a schema (XSD file) from xml, you could check Altova XMLSpy. It is a paid tool, though. I am sure you would find any open source tool, or something like that in the web.